# I cannot select an drop-down option with selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I tried selecting an option in the below HTML source.

```
<span class="card-payselect">
    <select name="selShiharai" onchange="chkShiharai_GLMP03()">
        <option value=''  SELECTED>選択してください
        <option value="1" >クレジットカード
        <option value="3" >コンビニ／ＡＴＭ
        <option value="4" >ネットバンキング
    </select>
</span>
```

I tried with the code:

```
IWebElement option= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span/select/option[@value=\"3\"]"));
option.Click();
```

Then the console printed from `option.GetAttribute("innerHTML")`:
コンビニ／ＡＴＭ

Also I tried with the code:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("selShiharai"))).SelectByText("コンビニ／ＡＴＭ");
```

But the program didn't select the option. Oddly it worked well on other computers. 
I use selenium 3.01 and firefox 47.0 version(32bit).

What's wrong in this situation? Thank you for reading.

Comment: have you tried using `index` : `new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("selShiharai"))).SelectByIndex(1);` ?

Comment: yes, I also tried that. but it's not working.

Comment: This is likely not related to your problem, but that HTML is incomplete - it's missing closing tags and quotes. Should be `<option value="3">コンビニ／ＡＴＭ</option>`

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing the following:

```
IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("card-payselect"));
dropdown.Click();

IList<IWebElement> listOfElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[@class='card-payselect']/select"));
listOfElements[2].Click();
```